# last row is inserted many times in store procedure what to do

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor

```
DECLARE candidate CURSOR FOR 
           SELECT `ce_agr_perc`, `ce_year_of_passing`, `ql_id`,`ua_id`, 
                  `sb_id`, `ps_id` ,`ce_id`, c_id   
           FROM `candidate_education` 
           WHERE c_id IN ( SELECT c_id FROM `candidate` ) 
           ORDER BY c_id;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET d = 0;

TRUNCATE TABLE `candidate_tag_string_copy`;
OPEN candidate;

read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH candidate 
     INTO ceagrperc, ceyearofpassing, qlid, uaid, sbid, psid, ceid, cid;

    IF d=1 THEN
       LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    IF NOT d=1 THEN
       SELECT ql_short_code INTO qlcode FROM qualification_level 
        WHERE ql_id=qlid;
       SELECT `us_short_code` INTO usshortcode FROM `university_affiliation` 
        WHERE ua_id=uaid;
       SELECT `short_code` INTO shortcode FROM `school_boards` 
        WHERE sb_id=sbid;
       SELECT `ds_id`,`dp_id` INTO dsid,dpid FROM `programe_specialization` 
        WHERE `ps_id`=psid; 
       SELECT `dp_short_code`, `dp_degree_edu_level` 
         INTO dpshortcode, dpdegreeedulevel 
         FROM `degree_programe` 
        WHERE `dp_id`=dpid; 
       SELECT `ds_short_code` INTO dsshortcode FROM `degree_specialization` 
        WHERE `ds_id`=dsid; 

       IF qlcode='UG' THEN  
          SELECT CONCAT( '{', qlcode,';', dpshortcode, '-', 
                              dsshortcode, ';', usshortcode, ';', 
                              ceagrperc, ';', ceyearofpassing, '}' ) 
            INTO ctsstring ; 
          INSERT 
            INTO `candidate_tag_string_copy`
                      ( `c_id`, `cts_tag_class`, `cts_fk_id`, `cts_string` )  
          VALUES( cid, 'edu', ceid, ctsstring );
       END IF;

       IF qlcode='PG' THEN 
          SELECT CONCAT( '{', qlcode, '::', ';', dpshortcode, '-', 
                              dsshortcode, ';', usshortcode, ';', 
                              ceagrperc, ';', ceyearofpassing, '}' ) 
            INTO ctsstring ; 
          INSERT 
            INTO `candidate_tag_string_copy`
                      ( `c_id`, `cts_tag_class`, `cts_fk_id`, `cts_string` )  
          VALUES(cid,'edu2',ceid,ctsstring);
       END IF;

       IF qlcode='XII' THEN 
          SELECT CONCAT( '{', qlcode, ';', dpshortcode,'-', 
                              dsshortcode, ';', usshortcode, ';', 
                              ceagrperc, ';', ceyearofpassing, '}' ) 
            INTO ctsstring ; 
          INSERT 
            INTO `candidate_tag_string_copy` 
                      (`c_id`, `cts_tag_class`, `cts_fk_id`, `cts_string` ) 
          VALUES( cid, 'edu', ceid, ctsstring ); 
       END IF; 

       IF qlcode='X' THEN 
          SELECT CONCAT( '{', qlcode, ';', dpshortcode, '-', 
                             dsshortcode, ';', usshortcode, ';', 
                             ceagrperc, ';', ceyearofpassing, '}' ) 
            INTO ctsstring ; 
          INSERT 
            INTO `candidate_tag_string_copy` 
                      ( `c_id`, `cts_tag_class`, `cts_fk_id`, `cts_string` ) 
          VALUES( cid, 'edu4', ceid, ctsstring ); 
       END IF;
    END IF;
END LOOP;

CLOSE candidate;
```

Comment: the first thing I do in a situation like this, is make sure all the code is indented properly.  you might have a simple error but your indenting makes is difficult to determine.

Comment: @user2071660: What is the default value declared for variable `d`? Is that `1` or `0`?

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation on [***Fetch Statement***](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems020.htm)

> *If you FETCH past the last row in the result set, the values of the target fields or variables are indeterminate and the `NOTFOUND` attribute returns `TRUE`.*

**Note**: Above statement was from Oracle cursors documentation, but applicable to others as well.

I am not sure how you declared default value for variable `d` to use with `cursor handler`. But, I strongly believe the issue is because of not handling the `d` (`not found`) value correctly.

If I were you, I would have coded like the following:

```
declare not_found boolean default false;
...
declare continue handler for not found set not_found = true;
...
read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH candidate 
     INTO ceagrperc, ceyearofpassing, qlid, uaid, sbid, psid, ceid, cid;

    IF not_found THEN
       LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;

    ...
    ...
end loop;
...
```